# How to set a timer in web3 event watcher?

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

I have a web3 event watcher set up in a Javascript file as such:

```
var a;
contract.events.allEvents(function(error, event){
   if (event.event == "Set") {
        a = event.returnValues['val'];
   }
});
```

When I run this file with `node eventWatcher.js` it will loop indefinitely and run the code within my conditionals every time an event occurs.

However, I want to keep a timer concurrently such that when a certain amount of time passes, I can unset the value of `a`. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: normally in JavaScript a `setTimer()` function is used. Isn't this function working for you? Correct me if I am wrong, but this question is more about Javascript and not Ethereum itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a time event you can just use a normal JavaScript timer.

```
var a;
contract.events.allEvents(function(error, event){
    if (event.event == "Set") {
        a = event.returnValues['val'];
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            a = '';
        }, (60 * 1000)); // clear a in 60 seconds
    }
});
```

If you only want to do this once on the timer rather than once whenever the event occurs, you may prefer to put the timer on a loop with `setInterval` and use a `get` inside the timer function to grab events, and display the most recent.